# Is there a mod for Doom 3 that emulates Doom 2?

Tags: mods, doom-2, doom-3

Feeling a bit nostalgic about Doom 2 today, I really want to play it, but every time I go back to an old game, the graphics are always worse than I remember.

Is there, or could there be, a mod for [Doom 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_3), that allows me to play [Doom 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_II:_Hell_on_Earth) in 3D?

Comment: Ah, I see classic doom mod (http://www.moddb.com/mods/classic-doom-3) but no Doom 2 yet.

Comment: it is not the graphics, it is the flat screen panel you are trying to use; it is too big, too flat and too bright; just use an old 14 inch CRT display

Comment: Yeah... just can't get over the sound of CRT magnetostriction, hah. I guess back then we didn't know any different but the sound drives me mad now... apparently I'm one of the unlucky few adults that can hear these high pitched frequencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's [Doom II wad for Doom 3](http://www.doomwadstation.com/doom3/maps/doom2/) which you can get from DoomWad Station.

You might also want to check out [Doomsday mod](http://forums.newdoom.com/forumdisplay.php?f=57), which isn't specifically for D3 engine, but still adds much better graphics and sound to a classic game.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is quite old, but your best option is to use [Doomsday Engine](http://dengine.net/), it adds all the feature that you are looking for 3d models, better lighting, TCP/IP support for networking and the very needed mouse-look support.

If you are looking to play Doom 1 or Doom 2. This is what I would recommend anytime you got some nostalgia.

Screenshot of the engine below:

[image]

Comment: 10 years later, you can use VoxelDoom, RayTracing Doom and HD Textures with it